# New magento storeview is not inheriting website configuration

Tags: magento, magento2.2

**Problem:** Creating a new storeview does not seem to 'connect' it to the website view, and thus it doesn't inherit its configuration. Also see screenshots below to make things more clear.

**Additional Information**

Between the last storeview we created, and the new one (Test), no real changes were made to the codebase. The shop has been running on version 2.2 ever since and no new extensions were installed.

I've tried to verify several things, such as checking whether the store was correctly linked to the website (in database table "store"). I also came across a bug, that supposedly existed in version 2.1.3 (as seen in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157925/magento-2-1-3-store-view-config-doesnt-inherit-website-config), I have verified that this fix is part of the code.

Saving the website config to hopefully overwrite the store config did not work, nor did flushing the entire cache (including cache on disk). No errors are shown in the logs whenever a new storeview is created or modified.

**Below you can see a specific setting (it happens to ALL settings) in website view**
[image: Website view]

**And below what it looks like in the "Test" storeview**
[image: Store view]

I'm a bit lost and not sure where to look anymore. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Makes sense, thanks, I'll be posting this there instead.